# How to configure vegaStream 50 europa 4fxs+2fxo on cent os 6

Tags: linux, centos, ip, fax

I have a Internet wire line with class A ip. I am trying to connect vegaStream 50 europa 4fxs+2fxo machine on my system but I am unable to get its ip and unable to reach to its web portal. please help.

Answer (score 1):

please connect analog phone to port fxs1, power on gateway, pickup handset and dial #1#1 after that please dial 111 to hear LAN1 IP address

please also check manual 
ftp://ftp.sangoma.com/vega/docs/Vega_Admin_Guide_R85_v1.6.pdf

p.s. I need help configuring Vega 50 europa 4fxs+2fxo on polish landline, cannot find polish dial tones (on Basic Config->Country is not listed PL)

kind regards, Piotr